# mapView does not show correctly in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

i have mapView in my dialog.
but map does not show correctly and there is some transparent space on view!

this is my xml :

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

init mapView :

```
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                mapView.onCreate(null);
                mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

onMapReady :

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        try {
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;

            MapsInitializer.initialize(getBaseActivity());
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mapView.onResume();

            mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraIdle() {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude,
                            mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbjZp.jpg)

please help me to fix this. thanks.

Comment: can you provide little more code ?? where you showing? how you initializing ?

Comment: @ShahadatHossainShaki 
i added more details to question.